# How to type only the first positional parameter of a Protocol method and let the others be untyped?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.9, duck-typing

## Problem

How to only type the first positional parameter of a Protocol method and let the others be untyped?

Example, having a protocol named `MyProtocol` that has a method named `my_method` that requires only the first positional parameter to be an int, while letting the rest be untyped.
the following class would implement it correctly without error:

```py
class Imp1(MyProtocol):
  def my_method(self, first_param: int, x: float, y: float) -> int:
    return int(first_param - x + y)
```

However the following implementation wouldn't implement it correctly, since the first parameter is a float:

```py
class Imp2(MyProtocol):
  def my_method(self, x: float, y: float) -> int: # Error, method must have a int parameter as a first argument after self
    return int(x+y)
```

I thought I would be able to do that with `*args`, and `**kwargs` combined with `Protocol` like so:

```py
from typing import Protocol, Any

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def my_method(self, first_param: int, /, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        ...
```

But (in mypy) this makes both Imp1 and Imp2 fail, because it forces the method contract to really have a `*args`, `**kwargs` like so:

```py
class Imp3(MyProtocol):
    def my_method(self, first_param: int, /, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        return first_param
```

But this does not solves what I am trying to achieve, that is make the implementation class have any typed/untyped parameters except for the first parameter.

## Workaround

I manged to circumvent the issue by using an abstract class with a setter `set_first_param`, like so:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class MyAbstractClass(ABC):
    _first_param: int

    def set_first_param(self, first_param: int):
        self._first_param = first_param

    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        ...


class AbcImp1(MyAbstractClass):
    def my_method(self, x: float, y: float) -> int:
        return int(self._first_param + x - y) # now i can access the first_parameter with self._first_param
```

But this totally changes the initial API that I am trying to achieve, and in my opinion makes less clear to the implementation method that this parameter will be set before calling `my_method`.

## Note

This example was tested using python version `3.9.13` and mypy version `0.991`.

Comment: No way, [fortunately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: You're not calling `super().__init__()` and similar, but you should be. Also, perhaps you can examine args with [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) at runtime, and signal an error if the contract is violated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `MyProtocol` can accept any number of arguments, you cannot have a subtype (or implementation) which accepts a set number, this breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) as the subtype only accepts a limited set of cases accepted by the supertype.

[original paragraph]

Then, if you keep on inheriting from `Protocol`, you keep on making protocols, protocols are different from `ABC`s, they use **structural subtyping** (not nominal subtyping), meaning that as long as an object implements all the methods/properties of a protocol it is an instance of that protocol (see [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) for more details).

[end original paragraph]

[edit upon further reading]

In my opinion, protocols should only be inherited by other protocols which will be used with structural subtyping. For nominal subtyping (which for instance allows default implementation) I would use ABCs.

[edit upon further reading]

Without more detail on the implementations you'd want to use, @blhsing's solution is probably the most open because it does not type the Callable's call signature.

Here is a set of implementations around a [generic protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#generic-protocols) with contravariant types (bound to float as it is the [top of the numeric tower](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)), which would allow any numeric type for the two `x` and `y` arguments.

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", contravariant=True, bound=float)
U = TypeVar("U", contravariant=True, bound=float)

class MyProtocol(Protocol[T, U]):
    def my_method(self, first_param: int, x: T, y: U) -> int:
        ...

class ImplementMyProtocol1(Generic[T, U]):
    """Generic implementation, needs typing"""
    def my_method(self, first_param: int, x: T, y: U) -> int:
        return int(first_param - x + y)

class ImplementMyProtocol2:
    """Float implementation, and ignores first argument"""
    def my_method(self, _: int, x: float, y: float) -> int:
        return int(x + y)

class ImplementMyProtocol3:
    """Another float implementation, with and extension"""
    def my_method(self, first_param: int, x: float, y: float, *args: float) -> int:
        return int(first_param - x + y + sum(args))

def use_MyProtocol(inst: MyProtocol[T, U], n: int, x: T, y: U) -> int:
    return inst.my_method(n, x, y)

use_MyProtocol(ImplementMyProtocol1[float, float](), 1, 2.0, 3.0)  # OK MyProtocol[float, float]
use_MyProtocol(ImplementMyProtocol1[int, int](), 1, 2, 3)  # OK MyProtocol[int, int]
use_MyProtocol(ImplementMyProtocol2(), 1, 2.0, 3.0)  # OK MyProtocol[float, float]
use_MyProtocol(ImplementMyProtocol3(), 1, 2.0, 3.0)  # OK MyProtocol[float, float]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I ended up doing something similar to this, but instead of using generic types for each extra param, I used a single generic type that could be a dataclass: https://gist.github.com/giuliano-oliveira/7d2194c9fcdd8f8071ccbd173461e037

Comment: I see you have still used the protocol as a parent in your implementation, this is most likely wrong. When your implementation inherits from your protocol it becomes a protocol itself, which by essence is not an implementation. Protocols use structural subtyping rather than nominal subtyping, i.e. **they don't need inheritance**.

Comment: I see, makes sense, but I am using basically what mypy suggests to do when you want to type check the subclass when instantiating it.
'Explicitly including a protocol as a base class is also a way of documenting that your class implements a particular protocol'

Is there some kind of missmatch between the PEP 544 and mypy?
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols

Comment: Ok, I had a further look and I must say I was incorrect, you can indeed inherit a protocol explicitly, which allows default implementations and such. I would rather have ABCs nominal inheritance and default implementation, and Protocols for interfaces, but that’s a personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable workaround would be to make the method take just the typed arguments, and leave the untyped arguments to a callable that the method returns. Since you can declare the return type of a callable without specifying the call signature by using an ellipsis, it solves your problem of leaving those additional arguments untyped:

```
from typing import Protocol, Callable

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def my_method(self, first_param: int) -> Callable[..., int]:
        ...

class Imp1(MyProtocol):
  def my_method(self, first_param: int) -> Callable[..., int]:
      def _my_method(x: float, y: float) -> int:
          return int(first_param - x + y)
      return _my_method

print(Imp1().my_method(5)(1.5, 2.5)) # outputs 6
```

Demo of the code passing mypy:

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=677569f73f6fc3bc6e44858ef37e9faf

Answer (score 0):

1. Signature of method 'Imp1.my_method()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'MyProtocol'

   must be I suppose

   ```
    class Imp1(MyProtocol):
        def my_method(self, first_param: int, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
            ...
   ```
2. Yours Imp2 the same as in Imp1 but does not even have first named parameter.